# making an undirected graph from a PPI (protein-protein interaction ) excel file

Tags: matlab, graph

I am new in MatLAB so I apologize for naive question. I want to make an undirected graph 
from a PPI network (protein-protein interaction) Excel file by MATLAB and to calculate
the shortest path length of the nodes.

I imported the Excel file into MATLAB and now I have a 2*1 matrix (the rows=2312) as
cell array. The first column is source and the next one is the target protein. Now, I have 
problem in sparsing the data and make adjacency matrix. In fact, I could not find any 
command to sparse the cell array or to make an adjacency matrix. I would appreciate for 
any suggestions to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly, you can use this method to build your adjacency matrix from sparse array.

For Example:

```
N=10;
Matrix=zeros(N);
Sparse=[1 7;3 5;2 6];

S=N.*(Sparse(:,1)-1)+Sparse(:,2);
Matrix=Matrix(:);
Matrix(S)=1;

Matrix=reshape(Matrix,[N N])';
```